# Cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) - No settings changed

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Has anyone already experienced same issue as ours?

No setting has been changed but suddenly everything in the Google Cloud SQL stopped working.

It says the instance is "runnable".

[image]

I cannot retrieve and create new User Accounts

[image]

Also with the databases

[image]

No detailed info about the errors are shown in the logs.

[image]

Anyone who has experienced the same issue and able to solve it?

Hoping for a swift response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the info if anyone has experienced the same issue and is still searching for a solution online.

Additional info for the issue :
Cloud SQL is totally unreachable even via command line or client.

Normally, if you encounter these kind of issues, you would try to restart the instance. 
However, even if you restart the instance in the cloud platform, the restart request would be in the "pending" state before it actually restarts itself.
It took hours before it restarted the instance.

Based on the activity log, this is the last logged action before it worked again.

Not sure though if that restart instance was the solution.

For immediate action, just contact the support.

[image]